# Increment array in python, like a base number system

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Say I have an array like [0 0 0 0] and I want to iterate it on a base-like scale. So say I pick base 100, and assume that I want to do it in a little endian system. My output would look like:
[1 0 0 0]
[2 0 0 0]
...
[99 0 0 0]
[0 1 0 0]

My code currently is in a function 'indexArray' but I was wondering it it was possible to do this without an if statement in a much simpler way?

```
def indexArray(enteredArr):
    enteredArr[0] += 1
    for i in range(len(enteredArr)):
        if enteredArr[i] > 99:
            enteredArr[i] = 0
            enteredArr[i + 1] += 1
    return enteredArr
```

Comment: Your example is actually in base 100.

Comment: pretty sure you're going to have to use a conditional..

Comment: You need a conditional. If you use numpy you can work on a larger number of digits in parallel, but if that’s really a speedup and/or easier to understand is debatable.

Comment: @randomir Doh! You are correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As usual in Python, there's an easier way if you look for it.

Your main loop could be:

```
for i in itertools.product(range(BASE), repeat=NDIM):
    ... stuff ...
```

For your example, BASE=100 and NDIM=4, but the same approach works for any other values.

`i` will be a tuple of array values counting up like `(0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 1) ... (BASE-1, BASE-1, BASE-1, BASE-1)`.

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for, a way to do what I was doing, but easier. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

```
num = 45
base = 3

num_base = []
remainder = num

# the remainders of the integer divisions of the number by the base are the digits of the number in the new base
# see also here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/111150/changing-a-number-between-arbitrary-bases
while remainder:
    num_base.append(remainder % base)
    remainder //= base

# join the list in reverse while changing type of digits to characters
print("".join(str(x) for x in num_base[::-1]))
```